# What are some reasons NHibernate will not execute SQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent

I am using Fluent NHibernate to map entities and am having a problem getting a repository to give a resultset.  In the console, the SQL does not show but other repositories do.  I have a feeling that it is because of the Mappings but can't tell why.  The table name includes an underscore which is one of the only differences between this repo and others.  My question is what could cause the sql not to be executed?

Here is my setup.

Entity:

```
   public class Org
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string IndividualName { get; set; }
        public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping:

```
public class OrgMap : ClassMap<Org>
{
    public OrgMap()
    {
        Table(@"Org_Updates");  // Also tried Table("Org_Updates");
        Map(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.IndividualName);
        Map(x => x.GroupName);
        Map(x => x.AddressLine1, "PhysicalLocationAddress");
        Map(x => x.AddressLine2, "PLAddr2");
```

Repository:

```
 public class OrgRepository : RepositoryBase<Org>, IOrgRepository
    {
        public IList<Org>GetTop50()
        {
            var query = All().AsList();
            return query;
         }
     }
```

RepositoryBase:

```
   public class OrgRepositoryBase<T> : RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        public OrgRepositoryBase()
        {
            var registry = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EventListenerRegistry>();
            registry.RegisterListenerForType<T>(GetType(), EventType.Save);
            registry.RegisterListenerForType<T>(GetType(), EventType.Delete);
        }

        protected override ISession GetSession()
        {
            return UnitOfWork.Current.GetSessionFromContext<ISession>(typeof (OrgModel));
        }

        protected override Type ModelType
        {

            get { return typeof (OrgModel); }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said before, the other repositories that use other entites/mapping work.  I can use this repository, exchanging the entity/mapping that it implements and it will work.  I'm pretty sure it's because of hte mapping but can't tell which part.  I have checked the table name and the column names.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If it was because of the mappings I think you'd get an error...

Comment: The SQL never shows in the console.  For others repos it will, and if i use a different entity in this repo, it will.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption here that your table does have a primary key. If so, should you not map that primary key

```
public class OrgMap : ClassMap<Org>
{
    public OrgMap()
    {
        Table(@"Org_Updates");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.IndividualName);
        Map(x => x.GroupName);
        Map(x => x.AddressLine1, "PhysicalLocationAddress");
        Map(x => x.AddressLine2, "PLAddr2");
```

Comment: I tried to change the to Id(x =>x.ID); but still no dice...  I had to stop working on this for a day or two but am about to get back at it.  I will update with any info.  Thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete mapping please.